# How router/roites could be injected in application in phalcon framework?

Tags: php, routes, phalcon

Here, in docs, is written about how to create routes:
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html

But i can't find how i can inject them in application.
What i need to do, to make my application use defined routes?

Should i inject router (or how?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The router can be registered in the DI (in your public/index.php) this way:

```
$di->set('router', function() {

    $router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router();

    $router->add("/login", array(       
        'controller' => 'login',
        'action' => 'index',
    ));

    $router->add("/products/:action", array(        
        'controller' => 'products',
        'action' => 1,
    ));

    return $router;
});
```

Also is possible to move the registration of routes to a separate file in your application (i.e app/config/routes.php) this way:

```
$di->set('router', function(){
    require __DIR__.'/../app/config/routes.php';
    return $router;
});
```

Then in the app/config/routes.php file:

```
<?php

$router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router();

$router->add("/login", array(       
    'controller' => 'login',
    'action' => 'index',
));

$router->add("/products/:action", array(        
    'controller' => 'products',
    'action' => 1,
));

return $router;
```

Examples: https://github.com/phalcon/php-site/blob/master/public/index.php#L33 and https://github.com/phalcon/php-site/blob/master/app/config/routes.php

Comment: The documentation on Phalcon's website leaves a lot to be desired.  Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, this is much more specific and add the liberty to add custom route so easly